# a divisibility problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

if $a$ is an integer , such that it is not divisible by 2 or 3, prove that $ 24 $ divides $ a^2+ 23$ .

I took cases ,case $1$ : when $a$ is divisible by only $2$ and not $3$ then we can write  $a = 6k+2, 6k+4 $ and case 2: when $a= 6k+3$ and here $a$ is divisible by only $3$ and not $2$. 
and then in each case,

I substituted values of $a$ in $a^2+23$ , but got nothing. I do think my case by- case analysis here is wrong, but surely I'm missing something .

please help by suggesting how can I improve my solution. No need to give me an elegant solution, only a few hints will be fine.

Comment: If $a$ is not supposed to be divisible by $2$ or $3$, then case 1 (where $a$ is divisible by $2$) and case 2 (where $a$ is divisible by $3$) are useless...

Answer (score 1):

**Method** $1:$

HINT:

Using [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html), $\lambda(24)=2$

If $(a,2)=(a,3)=1, (a,2^m\cdot3^n)=1$ for any integer $m\ge0,n\ge0$

So, $a^2\equiv1\pmod{24}$ if $(a,24)=1$

Now, $a^2+23\equiv a^2-1\pmod{24}$

**Method** $2:$

If $(a,3)=1, a\equiv\pm1\pmod 3$
$\implies a^2\equiv1\pmod 3\implies a^2+23\equiv24\pmod{3}\equiv0$

If $(a,2)=1, a=2b+1$(say),

$a^2=(2b+1)^2=8\frac{b(b+1)}2+1\equiv1\pmod 8$

$\implies a^2+23\equiv1+23\pmod 8\equiv 0$

So, $a^2+23$ is divisible by $3,8$ so will be divisible by lcm$(3,8)=24$

**Method** $3:$

HINT:
$$a^2+23=(a-1)(a+1)+24$$

Observe that $(a-1)a(a+1)$ being a product of $3$ three consecutive integers must be divisible by $3$

But as $(a,3)=1\implies 3$ divides $(a-1)(a+1)$

Again, as $(a,2)=1, a\pm1$ are even, one of them will be divisible by $2$, the other by $4$

$\implies 2\cdot4$ divides  $(a-1)(a+1)$

So, $(a-1)(a+1)$ is divisible by lcm$(3,8)=24$

Answer (score 1):

If a does not divide neither 2 nor 3, it does not divide 6. So , working with k, we see a must be of one of the forms $6k+1$ , or $6k-1$ , since $6k+2=2(3k+1), 6k+4=2(3k+2)$, etc.

Consider the first case, $a=6k+1$; then:

$a^2+23=(6k+1)^2+23=36k^2+12k+1+23=36k^2+12k+24=12k(3k+1)+24$ . But$k$ and $3k+1$ will
always have different parity, i.e., if $k$ is even, then $3k+1$ is odd--and viceversa.  So we have the cases:

1)If $k$ is even, we're done, since then:

$12k(3k+1)+24=12(2k')(3k+1)=24k'(3k+1)+24$

2)If $k$ is odd, then $3k+1$ is even, say $3k+1=2k''$, then:

$12k(3k+1)+24=12k(2k'')+24=24kk''+24$

The case for a=6k-1 is similar.

Comment: $$(6k\pm1)^2+23=36k^2\pm12k+24=24k^2+24\cdot\frac{k(k\pm 1)}2+24$$